# Как отфильтровать вывод LogCat для ACRA?

Tags: android

Решил использовать в своем проекте библиотеку ACRA для формирования и доставки отчетов от пользователей о работе приложения. Все мои отладочные сообщения пишутся в LogCat с помощью методов класса Log. В отчет они включены и именно в них 90% ценной информации. И если с эмулятора лог содержит только то, что нужно мне (а именно, мои сообщения и информация из printStackTrace()), то с реального устройства (SGS4) приходит еще и огромная куча ненужных строк, например:

```
D/ProgressBar(10716): setProgressDrawable mProgressDrawable = null, d = android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable@4257df18needUpdate = false
D/ProgressBar(10716): setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 0
D/ProgressBar(10716): setProgress = 0
D/ProgressBar(10716): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
D/ProgressBar(10716): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
D/ProgressBar(10716): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 228
I/endeffect(10716): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=750, getHeight()=1689, this=android.widget.ListView{427234a0 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-750,1689 #7f070083 app:id/menu_list}
I/endeffect(10716): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=750, getHeight()=1689, this=android.widget.ListView{427234a0 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-750,1689 #7f070083 app:id/menu_list}
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AbsListView(10716): Get MotionRecognitionManager
W/Resources(10716): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x3c a=-1}
W/Resources(10716): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x3c a=-1}
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): newFrequencyRequest  - mFrequency = 800000, mTimeoutMs = -1, mPkgName = LIST_SCROLL_BOOSTER@5
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): Boost Request from package = LIST_SCROLL_BOOSTER@5 frequency : 800000type = 6
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): !! pkgName = LIST_SCROLL_BOOSTER@5
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): Request from package name pkgName = LIST_SCROLL_BOOSTER@5
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): mToken is Null....Creating New Binder!
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): CPUDVFSControlRequest : doFrequencyRequest::  = 800000 Timeout : -1
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

И вот этими строками забито процентов 90 всего лога. Я же в них не вижу для себя какой-то ценности. Как их правильно отсеять, чтобы не задеть полезную информацию?

Сейчас в настройках библиотеки используется такая строка:

```
logcatArguments = { "-t", "300", "ru.bartwell.myapp:V" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот мой вариант решения:

```
logcatArguments = { "-t", "300", "MyAppTag:V", "System.err:V", "AndroidRuntime:V", "*:S" }
```